# Rails server fails to run when I close and reopen bash (ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

On a fresh run of Bash (on Ubuntu on Windows), if I try `rails s` I get this...

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails_generator/generators/applications/app/app_generator.rb:7: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
      exists
      exists  app/controllers
      exists  app/helpers
      exists  app/models
      exists  app/views/layouts
      exists  config/environments
      exists  config/initializers
      exists  config/locales
      exists  db
      exists  doc
      exists  lib
      exists  lib/tasks
      exists  log
      exists  public/images
      exists  public/javascripts
      exists  public/stylesheets
      exists  script/performance
      exists  test/fixtures
      exists  test/functional
      exists  test/integration
      exists  test/performance
      exists  test/unit
      exists  vendor
      exists  vendor/plugins
      exists  tmp/sessions
      exists  tmp/sockets
      exists  tmp/cache
      exists  tmp/pids
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  README
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
   identical  config/database.yml
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
   identical  db/seeds.rb
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
   identical  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]
```

It's no problem, I just put `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` and it's sorted... but I don't really want to have to do that every time...

This is my .bashrc file...

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells. see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the
# package bash-doc) for examples If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    i) ;;
      *) return;; esac
# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history. See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000 HISTFILESIZE=2000
# check the window size after each command and, if necessary, update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize
# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more
#directories and subdirectories. shopt -s globstar
# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;; esac
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned off by default to not distract the
#user: the focus in a terminal window should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes
if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
# We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48 (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely
# rare, and such a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
color_prompt=yes
    else color_prompt=
    fi
fi
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;; *)
    ;; esac
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r -/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b -/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto' alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'
    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF' alias la='ls -A' alias l='ls -CF'
# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed
-e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
# Alias definitions. You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like ~/.bash_aliases, instead
# of adding them here directly. See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable this, if it's already enabled in
# /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH" export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH" export
INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH" export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \.
"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" # This
loads nvm bash_completion export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$PATH"
export FACEBOOK_APP_ID=AsIfIWouldPostThisOnHere
export FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET=AsIfIWouldPostThisOnHere

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session as a function

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

And .bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

export FACEBOOK_APP_ID=ObviouslyNotTheRealIdFromMyFile
export FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET=ItsASecret

source ~/.profile
```

I'm new to Bash on Ubuntu on Windows so I'm probably doing something stupid as I've cobbled together bits of information for different sites. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't have to do it manually if it's in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file, so maybe see why that isn't loading.

Comment: Check this link out, specifically the part about changing your shell to run commands as "login shell". https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal
This is an odd rvm thing that always gets me on fresh ubuntu installs.

Comment: This seems wierd, why is the generator running when you do `rails s`?

Comment: @maxpleaner I know! It treats it like `rails new s` and creates a new app. A serious WTF there...

Comment: @0101001101000010 Unfortunately I am running Bash on Ubuntu on Windows... I don't have those options...

Comment: @tadman thanks for the answer, but I'm too much of a bash n00b to follow your advice...

Comment: @dennispreston, basically, if that's the answer just do `sudo vim .bashrc` and add it. You do that by pressing the `i` on your keyboard, which stands for insert. Once, you have added that script, you do `esc` + `wq` which stands for escape + save and quit.